# Can you reset Google Cloud Platform Firewall settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform

INGRESS is set to port 22 for all instances.
SSHD is installed and running. 
Anyway to delete all firewall rules and have the defaults reset?

I am lost.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a command or button to reset the firewall rules to its initial state; however, if you want to have the same firewall rules you had when you created your project, you can delete all the firewall rules you have created, and then you can recreate the four default firewall rules mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules):

default-allow-internal 
default-allow-ssh 
default-allow-rdp 
default-allow-icmp

The word default is used here because of the name of the VPC they work for (default); however, they can be named differently as well as they accomplish the following requirements:

- default-allow-internal: 
  Allows ingress connections for all protocols and ports among instances in the VPC. Permits incoming connections to VM instances from others in the same network.
- default-allow-ssh: 
  Allows ingress connections on TCP port 22 from any source to any instance in the network.
- default-allow-rdp: 
  Allows ingress connections on TCP port 3389 from any source to any instance in the network. Enables connections  via RDP.
- default-allow-icmp: 
  Allows ingress ICMP traffic from any source to any instance in the network.

I found the following [link](https://geekflare.com/gcp-firewall-configuration/) where you can see the default rules and how to create them. You can also see how to create the rules in the [oficial document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)